# Can I build my own backend service using uber api?

Tags: uber-api

I need to make my own application with 90% of uber features 
Can I build my own backend service using uber api?

I mean create my own server side and use uber algorithms,
Drivers and customers register with me not uber

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has some questionable legal implications in addition to asking about an off site resource and being too broad. The answer is pretty good though.

Answer (score 8):

Uber's software (including their API) is [proprietary](https://www.uber.com/legal/terms/us/). This means you can use the Uber API to build apps that either help riders book rides or help drivers perform their tasks more efficiently, but [you are not allowed to charge a fee atop Uber's base fee](https://developer.uber.com/support). Furthermore, Uber's algorithms for ride pricing and pathfinding remain closed-source and unavailable to Uber API developers.

On the other hand, you may be interested in [LibreTaxi](http://libretaxi.org/). Since it is [released](https://github.com/ro31337/libretaxi/blob/master/LICENSE) under the [MIT license](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/), the entire codebase is [available](https://github.com/ro31337/libretaxi) for you to read, extend, and use to run your own services. You can operate a business using the codebase and charge customers.

By contrast, Uber's API only exposes an interface for use by client programs and some example apps. (i.e. [Uber's Github repos](https://github.com/uber) do not contain the source code for their entire infrastructure.)